# Google Analytics: Track pages where ad's can be shown

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a page where users can post documents. I have paid users and free users. An URL to a document page looks like this:

```
www.domain.com/document/read/12345
```

The last part is the document ID. If the document ID 12345 is from a free user, I show ad's on the page. If the document ID 12345 is from a paid user, I don't show ad's.

Now I want to track how much traffic I have from pages where I can display the ad's. Of course I also want to track the whole traffic. At the end I want to say how much traffic I have for advertising ...

```
if (document_id == from_a_free_user) {
    call_google_analytics_and_count
}
```

A JS variable which indicates that the impressions is from a free or paid user exists and can be for example:

```
var paid_user (bool)
```

How to solve this with GA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) in your GA property. You can give it a name that is used in the Interface, e.g. "Paying User". However in the code you address the dimension by the "dimension" keyword and the numeric index for your dimension, so for your first custom dimension this would be `dimension1`.

Custom dimensions expect a string value, so you have to set a value based on your variables:

```
var is_paying_user = "no";
if (document_id == from_a_free_user) {
    is_paying_user = "yes";
}
ga('set', 'dimension1', is_paying_user);
ga('send','pageview');
```

The custom dimension value is now attached to any hit that follow the "set" call.

The value does not appear by default in the standard reports. However you can select it as secondary dimension, use it in custom reports or use it for segmentation.